# How to change the href attribute for a hyperlink using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, hyperlink

How can you change the `href` attribute (link target) for a hyperlink using jQuery?

Comment: For those of you interested in solutions ***without*** the usage of jQuery - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery/28016553#28016553

Comment: For newer jQuery versions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6348239/4928642

Comment: the simplest example without jQuery https://stackoverflow.com/a/39276418/696535

Comment: A complete list of possible solutions, some useful selectors and way to get the value of matches of regex and use them to update href: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49568546/1262248

Answer (score 2068, accepted):

Using

```
$("a").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/")
```

will modify the href of all hyperlinks to point to Google. You probably want a somewhat more refined selector though. For instance, if you have a mix of link source (hyperlink) and link target (a.k.a. "anchor") anchor tags:

```
<a name="MyLinks"></a>
<a href="http://www.codeproject.com/">The CodeProject</a>
```

...Then you probably don't want to accidentally add `href` attributes to them. For safety then, we can specify that our selector will only match `<a>` tags with an existing `href` attribute:

```
$("a[href]") //...
```

Of course, you'll probably have something more interesting in mind. If you want to match an anchor with a specific existing `href`, you might use something like this:

```
$("a[href='http://www.google.com/']").attr('href', 'http://www.live.com/')
```

This will find links where the `href` exactly matches the string `http://www.google.com/`. A more involved task might be matching, then updating only part of the `href`:

```
$("a[href^='http://stackoverflow.com']")
   .each(function()
   { 
      this.href = this.href.replace(/^http:\/\/beta\.stackoverflow\.com/, 
         "http://stackoverflow.com");
   });
```

The first part selects only links where the href *starts* with `http://stackoverflow.com`. Then, a function is defined that uses a simple regular expression to replace this part of the URL with a new one. Note the flexibility this gives you - any sort of modification to the link could be done here.

Comment: For completeness, since this is still being linked to occasionally, I'll add that since jQuery 1.4, the last example doesn't require using `each` - the following would now be possible: `$(selector).attr('href', function() { return this.replace(/.../, '...'); });`

Comment: @DavidHedlund your function doesn't work. It produces "this.replace is not a function".
It should be: `$('a[href]').attr('href', function(i, val) { return val.replace(/.*/, 'xy')});`

Answer (score 317):

With jQuery 1.6 and above you should use:

```
$("a").prop("href", "http://www.jakcms.com")
```

The difference between `prop` and `attr` is that `attr` grabs the HTML attribute whereas `prop` grabs the DOM property.

You can find more details in this post: [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: An explanation why you should use `prop` over `attr` would be appreciated, for people coming to the question and finding `attr` apparently working perfectly fine in newer jQuery versions...

Answer (score 90):

Use the `attr` method on your lookup. You can switch out any attribute with a new value.

```
$("a.mylink").attr("href", "http://cupcream.com");
```

Answer (score 49):

<sub>Even though the OP explicitly asked for a jQuery answer, you don't need to use jQuery for everything these days.</sub>

### A few methods without jQuery:

- If you want to change the `href` value of ***all*** `<a>` elements, select them all and then iterate through the [nodelist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList): [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/kqw7h1nq/)

  ```
  var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(anchors, function (element, index) {
      element.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
  });
  ```
- If you want to change the `href` value of all `<a>` elements that actually have an `href` attribute, select them by adding the `[href]` attribute selector (`a[href]`): [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/pLkr9497/)

  ```
  var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a[href]');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(anchors, function (element, index) {
      element.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
  });
  ```
- If you want to change the `href` value of `<a>` elements that *contain* a specific value, for instance `google.com`, use the attribute selector `a[href*="google.com"]`: [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/eLw5svh2/)

  ```
  var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="google.com"]');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(anchors, function (element, index) {
      element.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
  });
  ```

  Likewise, you can also use the other [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). For instance:

  - `a[href$=".png"]` could be used to select `<a>` elements whose `href` value ends with `.png`.
  - `a[href^="https://"]` could be used to select `<a>` elements with `href` values that are *prefixed* with `https://`.
- If you want to change the `href` value of `<a>` elements that satisfy multiple conditions: [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/8fxekxLu/)

  ```
  var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="https://"], a[href$=".png"]');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(anchors, function (element, index) {
      element.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
  });
  ```

..no need for regex, in *most* cases.

Answer (score 46):

Depending on whether you want to change all the identical links to something else or you want control over just the ones in a given section of the page or each one individually, you could do one of these.

Change all links to Google so they point to Google Maps:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">

$("a[href='http://www.google.com/']").attr('href', 
'http://maps.google.com/');
```

To change links in a given section, add the container div's class to the selector. This example will change the Google link in the content, but not in the footer:

```
<div class="content">
    <p>...link to <a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>
    in the content...</p>
</div>

<div class="footer">
    Links: <a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>
</div>

$(".content a[href='http://www.google.com/']").attr('href', 
'http://maps.google.com/');
```

To change individual links regardless of where they fall in the document, add an id to the link and then add that id to the selector. This example will change the second Google link in the content, but not the first one or the one in the footer:

```
<div class="content">
    <p>...link to <a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>
    in the content...</p>
    <p>...second link to <a href="http://www.google.com/" 
        id="changeme">Google</a>
    in the content...</p>
</div>

<div class="footer">
    Links: <a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>
</div>

$("a#changeme").attr('href', 
'http://maps.google.com/');
```

Answer (score 18):

Try this;

```
$("#link").attr("href", "https://coenvink.com/")
```

A breakdown of what the code does:

```
$("#link")
```

This part of the code gets the element with id "Link". After this you set the attribute 'href' (witch is basically the link-to-url) to your new url, witch, in this case, is my own website:

```
.attr("href", "https://coenvink.com/")
```

I hope it is clear now!

Answer (score 16):

The simple way to do so is :

**[Attr function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) (since jQuery version 1.0)**

```
$("a").attr("href", "https://stackoverflow.com/")
```

or

**[Prop function](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2) (since jQuery version 1.6)**

```
$("a").prop("href", "https://stackoverflow.com/")
```

Also, the advantage of above way is that if selector selects a single anchor, it will update that anchor only and if selector returns a group of anchor, it will update the specific group through one statement only.

Now, there are lot of ways to identify exact anchor or group of anchors:

**Quite Simple Ones:**

1. Select anchor through tag name : `$("a")`
2. Select anchor through index:  `$("a:eq(0)")`
3. Select anchor for specific classes (as in this class only anchors
   with class `active`) : `$("a.active")`
4. Selecting anchors with specific ID (here in example `profileLink`
   ID) : `$("a#proileLink")`
5. Selecting first anchor href: `$("a:first")`

**More useful ones:**

6. Selecting all elements with href attribute : `$("[href]")`
7. Selecting all anchors with specific href: `$("a[href='www.stackoverflow.com']")`
8. Selecting all anchors not having specific href: `$("a[href!='www.stackoverflow.com']")`
9. Selecting all anchors with href containing specific URL: `$("a[href*='www.stackoverflow.com']")`
10. Selecting all anchors with href starting with specific URL: `$("a[href^='www.stackoverflow.com']")`
11. Selecting all anchors with href ending with specific URL: `$("a[href$='www.stackoverflow.com']")`

Now, if you want to amend specific URLs, you can do that as:

For instance if you want to add proxy website for all the URLs going to google.com, you can implement it as follows:

```
$("a[href^='http://www.google.com']")
   .each(function()
   { 
      this.href = this.href.replace(/http:\/\/www.google.com\//gi, function (x) {
        return "http://proxywebsite.com/?query="+encodeURIComponent(x);
    });
   });
```

Answer (score 13):

Stop using jQuery just for the sake of it! This is so simple with JavaScript only.

```
document.querySelector('#the-link').setAttribute('href', 'http://google.com');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bo77f8mg/1/

Answer (score 12):

This snippet invokes when a link of class 'menu_link' is clicked, and shows the text and url of the link. The return false prevents the link from being followed.

```
<a rel='1' class="menu_link" href="option1.html">Option 1</a>
<a rel='2' class="menu_link" href="option2.html">Option 2</a>

$('.menu_link').live('click', function() {
   var thelink = $(this);
   alert ( thelink.html() );
   alert ( thelink.attr('href') );
   alert ( thelink.attr('rel') );

   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 9):

`href` in an attribute, so you can change it using pure JavaScript, but if you already have jQuery injected in your page, don't worry, I will show it both ways:

Imagine you have this `href` below:

```
<a id="ali" alt="Ali" href="http://dezfoolian.com.au">Alireza Dezfoolian</a>
```

And you like to change it the link...

Using **pure JavaScript** without any library you can do:

```
document.getElementById("ali").setAttribute("href", "https://stackoverflow.com");
```

But also in **jQuery** you can do:

```
$("#ali").attr("href", "https://stackoverflow.com");
```

or

```
$("#ali").prop("href", "https://stackoverflow.com");
```

In this case, if you already have jQuery injected, probably jQuery one look shorter and more cross-browser...but other than that I go with the `JS` one...

Answer (score 6):

```
 $("a[href^='http://stackoverflow.com']")
   .each(function()
   { 
      this.href = this.href.replace(/^http:\/\/beta\.stackoverflow\.com/, 
         "http://stackoverflow.com");
   });
```

Answer (score 4):

## Change the HREF of the Wordpress Avada Theme Logo Image

If you install the ShortCode Exec PHP plugin the you can create this Shortcode which I called myjavascript

```
?><script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("div.fusion-logo a").attr("href","tel:303-985-9850");
});
</script>
```

You can now go to Appearance/Widgets and pick one of the footer widget areas and use a text widget to add the following shortcode

```
[myjavascript]
```

The selector may change depending upon what image your using and if it's retina ready but you can always figure it out by using developers tools.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
link.href = 'https://...'
```

```js
link.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com'
```

```html
<a id="link" href="#">Click me</a>
```