# Adding an anchor to generated URLs

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, anchor

I have tried finding a simialr example and using that to answer my problem, but I can't seem to get it to work, so apologies if this sounds similar to other problems.

Basically, I am using Terminal Four's Site Manager CMS system to build my websites. This tool allows you to generate navigation elements to use through out your site.

I need to add a custom bit of JS to append to these links an anchor.

The links generated are similar to this:

```
<ul id="tab-menu">
<li><a href="/section/page">test link, can i rewrite and add an anchor!!!</a></li>
</ul>
```

I can edit the css properties of the link, but I can't figure out how to add an anchor.

The JQuery I am using is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery.com/src/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    // everything goes here

    $("#tab-menu").children("li").each(function() { 
        $(this).children("a").css({color:"red"});

        });

    });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Paddy

Comment: Good question, but how does one do it without jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice jQuery-based method is to use the .get(index) method to access the raw DOM element within your each() function. This then gives you access to the JavaScript link object, which has a property called 'hash' that represents the anchor part of a url. So amending your code slightly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    // everything goes here

        $("#tab-menu").children("li").children("a").each(function() {   
            $(this).css({color:"red"}).get(0).hash = "boom";
        });

    });
```

Would change all the links in "#tab_menu li" to red, and attach "#boom" to the end.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Cool. How could one how one do it without jQuery?

Answer (score 3):

sort of duplicate of this:
[How to change the href for a hyperlink using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery)

just copy the old href and add anchor to it and paste that back

```
var link = $(this).children("a").attr("href");
$(this).children("a").attr("href", link+ "your own stuff");
```

Answer (score 0):

I can now target the html by using the following:

```
$(this).children("a").html("it works");
```

I assumed that:

```
$(this).children("a").href("something");
```

would edit the href but I am wrong.

Paddy

Comment: Use something like $(this).children("a").attr("href","something") and you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure for the answer, I dint try

```
$("#tab-menu").children("li").children("a").each(function() {   
              //  $(this).css({color:"red"}).get(0).hash = "boom";
            var temp_url = $(this).href +'#an_anchor';//or var temp_url = $(this).attr('href');
          $(this).attr('href', temp_url);
    });
```