# Using Jquery and regular expressions to change part of HREF

Tags: jquery, regex

I am currently trying to use Jquery to change the href attribute of a link within a DIV so that the URL is changed from file.html to file.jpg...

```
<div class="gallery">
<a href="file.html">My File</a>
```

and I want to change it to

```
<div class="gallery">
<a href="file.jpg">My File</a>
```

I have seen the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery) about changing the href attribute using Jquery and understand some of it, but I am at a complete loss about how to change all links ending .html within the div to .jpg. The filename doesn't need to change. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction for help?

Answer (score 4):

Try one of these:

```
$("div.gallery a").each(function() {
    this.setAttribute("href", this.getAttribute("href").replace(/\.html$/, ".jpg"));
});

$("div.gallery a[href$=.html]").each(function() {
    var href = this.getAttribute("href");
    this.setAttribute("href", href.substr(0, href.length-6) + ".jpg"));
});
```

The first will select every `a` inside your `div` and try to replace `.html` at the end with `.jpg` using a regular expression. The the second will only select those that’s `href` value does end with `.html` and will replace it with `.jpg` using simple string operations.

Answer (score 1):

Just extract the existing hrefs for elements whose href matches your pattern, then use string replacement to get the new href and set it.

```
$('a[href$=.html]').each( function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var href = $this.attr('href').replace(/\.html/,'.jpg');
    $this.attr('href', href );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var href=$(".gallery a").attr("href");
href=href.replace(/\.html$/,".jpg");
$(".gallery a").attr("href",href);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but I think this should do it:

```
$('a', '.gallery').each(function(){
   $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace(/\.html$/, '.jpg'));
});
```