# How do I change the "href" of <a> through Javascript Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have this:

```
<a id="main_link" href="http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/AmazonWire/~5/FN5UZlXKwdY/SalmanRushdiePodcast.mp3">
```

How do I use Jquery to change the "href" to something else?

Comment: Holy, just discovered this was actually a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery alex, how did you not see that previously asked question when you posted this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get a reference to your link, and use the [`attr`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr) method on it:

```
$('#main_link').attr('href', 'something_else');
```

That grabs the elements with `id="main_link"` using the id [`"#"` css selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/id) (should only be one in the document), and sets the `href` attribute of all (again, should only be one in the document).

jQuery can perform the exact same operation on batch to a class of elements:

```
$('.main_link').attr('href', 'something_else');
```

That grabs the elements with css `class="main_link"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

> $("#main_link").attr("href","http://...");

http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#main_link').attr('href','your new href');
```