# javascript for changing link's href in html page

Tags: javascript, html, href

My problem is the following:

I have a page with many links
Some of them have a specific pattern :

`http://www.example.com/.../?parameter1=...&parameter2=PARAMETER2`

What i want to do is to change these links' href to the value of the parameter2 using JavaScript.
For example if i have a link like :

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/.../?parameter1=...&parameter2=PARAMETER2">text here</a>
```

what i want to do after the script runs is to have a link like this:

```
<a href="PARAMETER2">text here</a>
```

Any suggestion would be truly appreciated!!!
Thank you all in advance!!!

Comment: possible Dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365246/how-to-change-href-of-a-tag-on-button-click-through-javascript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766133/how-do-i-change-the-href-of-a-through-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [jquery](http://jquery.com/)

then use the following code

```
$(function() {
  $("a[href^='www.example.com']").each(function(){
    var ele = $(this);
    var href = ele.attr("href");console.log(href);
    var index = href.lastIndexOf("parameter2");
    var param_2 = href.substring((index + 11));
    ele.attr("href", param_2);
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer..your code works fine but it changes all links.. Is there a way to define to change only for example www.example.com links???

Comment: i have changed the post.Please try that!

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/LVNeC/

```
function getUrlVars(_url)
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = _url.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}

var myLINK = document.getElementById("mylink");
var url = myLINK.href;
myLINK.href = getUrlVars(url )["parameter2"];​
```

Comment: thank you for your answer..I'll try it to see how it works and I'll provide a feedback..