# Replace link location (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, replace, hyperlink, attributes, location

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">link</a>
```

How do I replace link location from google.com to say "#"? `$('a').attr( 'href', '#' );` isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me.

Test code:

```
<a id="MyLink" href="test.html">
```

jQuery:

```
$("#MyLink").attr("href", "#");
alert($("#MyLink").attr("href")); //alerts "#"
```

Is it possible you are trying to do this before the DOM has loaded?

Also, what browsers are you using?

**EDIT:**

To ensure this is only done when the DOM is loaded completely, use the document `.ready()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#MyLink").attr("href", "#");

    //other initialisation, e.g. event binding
});
```

Comment: Ah yes, how do I delay this until the DOM has loaded completely?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question - [How to change the href for a hyperlink using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery)