# How replace a part of an object attibute using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, src

People, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery) I got some answers how to replace part of a HREF attribute of a link. Eventhough I didn't understand how the "////\"'s works.

I need to do the following:
A code that replace, in each "A IMG", the SRC 1.bp.blogspot.com/_YfY-Tbu-shE/S3q2T9SJQxI/AAAAAAAAAI8/w0kTOPwaxqs/**s1600-h**/TELA%204.png to 1.bp.blogspot.com/_YfY-Tbu-shE/S3q2T9SJQxI/AAAAAAAAAI8/w0kTOPwaxqs/**s1600**/TELA%204.png. Resuming: remove the **-h** from the SRC.

Could also explain, with examples, the "////\"'s tricks please? (or a page that shows it - didn't understand the examples in jQuery page)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

patrick provided a nice way of removing the "-h" from the URL, with the noted exception of problems that might occur if the pattern "-h" shows up elsewhere in the URL, but I wanted to see if I could help by showing this as part of a more complete solution.

```
$(function() {
    $('img[src*="s1600-h"]').each(function() {
        var newSrc = $(this).attr('src');
        newStr = newSrc.replace(/-h/,'');
        $(this).attr('src', newSrc);
    });
});
```

What this does is look for all "img" tags with an src containing `s1600-h`. Then, using a simple regular expression replacement, we take out the "-h", and update the src accordingly. You can work on refining these patterns if you find that certain things need to change, like s1600 being different each time? Or if the "-h" needs to be more specific.

Good luck!

Comment: This will work given a very specific set of circumstances (url with s1600-h and no other -h occurrances).