# How to update (append to) an href in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a list of links that all go to a google maps api.

the links already have the `daddr` (destination) parameter in them as static. I am using Geo-Location to find the users position and I want to add the `saddr` (source address) to the links once I get the data.

so basically I will need to add something like `&saddr=50.1234567,-50.03452` at the tail end of all the links pointing to google maps

All the links have a class called `directions-link`

and from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery) I have figured out how to change them:

```
$("a.directions-link").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/");
```

However I only want to append my value to the end of the href without changing what the href already is.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

```
var _href = $("a.directions-link").attr("href");
$("a.directions-link").attr("href", _href + '&saddr=50.1234567,-50.03452');
```

To loop with `each()`

```
$("a.directions-link").each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);       
   var _href = $this.attr("href"); 
   $this.attr("href", _href + '&saddr=50.1234567,-50.03452');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, will this work if there is more than 1 directions-link all with different hrefs? Thank you!

Comment: If you are appending the same thing for each instance of `a.directions-link` then yes. Otherwise, if you are appending  a different value to each href, you will need to use an `each()` to iterate and append the respective value.

Comment: I am appending the same value, but each href is different to begin with. so if the first is one.html and the second is two.html they both end up being one.html&saddr... because its capturing only the href of the first a.directions-link and using that for all. So I think I need to use each(). Do you care to eleborate on the use of that? Thanks!!

Comment: Yep, the loop is what I needed, Thanks! :)

Answer (score 49):

jQuery 1.4 has a new feature for doing this, and it rules. I've forgotten what it's called, but you use it like this:

```
$("a.directions-link").attr("href", function(i, href) {
  return href + '?q=testing';
});
```

That loops over all the elements too, so no need for $.each

Comment: That didn't work for me but `.attr('href', function(i) { return $(this).attr('href') + '?q=testing'; })` did.

Comment: @elfbertf it works for me. Are you using jquery >= 1.4? And did you include the href variable as the second argument?

Comment: $("#calculator").attr("href", function (i, href) {
                    return href + '?ves=' + 23 + '&v='+ 'sdfds';
                }); not work

Comment: Testing this at https://jsfiddle.net/qz9eLr2z/ , it works. http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function says this was added in jQuery 1.1.

Comment: @JacobC. Allowing attr to take a function was added in 1.1, but passing the current value as the second param was added in 1.4. Here's an example of it not working in jquery 1.3 https://jsfiddle.net/qz9eLr2z/1/

Comment: @zaius Thanks, you're quite right. Sorry about that. They really should put a note saying that in the documentation; as it stands right now, the documentation is misleading.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("a.directions-link").attr("href", $("a.directions-link").attr("href")+"...your additions...");
```

Comment: This is wrong. It applies the href from the first matched ".directions-link" to all links of that class. https://jsfiddle.net/yuezewaw/

Answer (score -1):

Here is what i tried to do to add parameter in the url which contain the specific character in the url.

```
jQuery('a[href*="google.com"]').attr('href', function(i,href) {
        //jquery date addition
        var requiredDate = new Date();
        var numberOfDaysToAdd = 60;
        requiredDate.setDate(requiredDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd); 
        //var convertedDate  = requiredDate.format('d-M-Y');
        //var newDate = datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', requiredDate );
        //console.log(requiredDate);

        var month   = requiredDate.getMonth()+1;
        var day     = requiredDate.getDate();

        var output = requiredDate.getFullYear() + '/' + ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day;
        //
```

Working Example [Click](http://jsfiddle.net/nasabikram/d4s4wt94)

Comment: What's the purpose of this post? Is this a question or an answer? Or just an odd comment? If it's the later, you're posting in the wrong place. ;-)

Comment: I have created the demo sample in jsfiddle, but the link was wrong. Now it point to right url.

Comment: Your 'answer' makes no sense, it's actually more of a bizarre statement.