# Append to the end of an href value with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I`ve got this link:

```
<a id="Link" href="mailto:bestellung@i-drain.net?subject=I-Drain Bestellung&body="></a>
```

Now i want to append data from an form element after &body="

So for example the first time it changes to `&body="New text` , and the next time it changes to
`&body="New text , Another text`.

How can i do this? Can´t get it to work.. thank you :)

Comment: More code please so we can adjust it to your needs

Comment: Please post the code which you have tried that did not work.

Comment: Duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805742/how-to-update-append-to-an-href-in-jquery

Comment: i´ve read this before, but solutions didn´t work for my case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You change the attribute of the link:

```
var link = $('#Link');
link.attr('href', link.attr('href') + 'your text');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use pure JS :

```
var el = document.getElementById('link');
el.href += 'some string';
```

When possibile, always try to use JS over jQuery, usually, it will provide better performance since it reduce the number of functions call.

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can do it with:

```
var form = $('.form_element').val();
var el = $('a#Link').prop('href');

el.prop('href', el.prop('href')+form);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#Link').attr('href',$('#Link').attr('href')+"New Text")
```