# Changing the href of a button and going to next page

Tags: jquery

I have created a button on my page that its HTML looks like this:

[image]

Now in my JavaScript I have a jQuery that finds that button like this:

```
 $('.personlistbtn').click(function(e) {
    console.log("inside click event of person list");
    console.log("provider id was this " + provider_id);
    // ????? 
  });
```

I want to attach some parameters to my href button that posted above so it can go to a new page in my Rails app with those parameters I am passing to it so hopefullu something like this:

```
<a href="/pharmacy/patients?provider_id=234" >
```

Notice I attached that **?provider_id=234** to it.
How can I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805742/how-to-update-append-to-an-href-in-jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `provider_id` is already set elsewhere in your code, this should work:

```
$('.personlistbtn a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.assign(this.href + '?provider_id=' + provider_id);
});
```

Comment: my href at first was /pharmacy/patients  now it shows as /pharmacy/undefined

Comment: @EricFromSouthPark this code does not interfere with the HTML code at all, it just redirects on click based on the values it has access to.

Comment: @EricFromSouthPark, do you get a value from `provider_id` in your console? maybe that is what is not working?

Comment: @Sergio : yep, provider_id has a value.

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit the href attr:

```
 $('.personlistbtn').on('click', function() {
     var $a = $(this).find('a');
     var href = $a.attr('href');
     $a.attr('href', href + '?provider_id=234');
 });
```

EDIT:

That code will work when clicking on the container div. If you want to attach the parameters when clicking on the anchor, you should do the following:

```
 $('.personlistbtn').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     window.location = $(this).attr('href') + '?provider_id=234';
 });
```

Comment: `$(this)` inside that click function  has no href. `$(this)` refers to the div. Add `a` after class and a `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Note that the page will already have performed the redirect to the original `href` value before you get to set the new value.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : Then this approach won't work for me. I want to first set those parameters and then make the call so the Rails controller can work on those params and show the right content on the page.

Comment: Sorry, you should add a .find('a') to the $(this)

Comment: @Servani : Can you please update the code to the more correct thing you think it should be ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.personlistbtn a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var provider_id = '?provider_id=234'; // this you already have, I just put it to have a value
    var newurl = this.href + '?provider_id=' + provider_id
    window.location.assign(newurl);
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uFZ5b/show/)**