# Append new path in all the a href URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have seen the post [How to update (append to) an href in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805742/how-to-update-append-to-an-href-in-jquery/2805755) , but it doesn't seem like the answer can help at my case.

I am currently using a plugin(easytab) to create a few different tab and every tab contains a tag like `<a id="tabopen" href="www.text.com/custom/questions/ask/">`

`<a id="tabopen" href="www.text.com/default/questions/ask/">`

and for some reason I have a button which append some extra path to all the href in order to redirect user to the right place.

I have tried to use

```
$("a#tab1").each(function() {
   var _href = $(this).attr("href"); 
   $(this).attr("href", _href + 'startDate=20160121?endDate=20160212');
});
```

but instead append the `'startDate=20160121?endDate=20160212'` it replace everything to `www.text.com/custom/questions/ask/startDate=20160121?endDate=20160212` , which is not right, how should i fix it?

**Update 1:**
I am sorry that i have provide wrong description at, the ids are actually the same in the plugin.

`<a id="tabopen" href="www.text.com/custom/questions/ask/">`

`<a id="tabopen" href="www.text.com/default/questions/ask/">`

Comment: `$("a#tab1")` will select only a **single** element. Use `$('a[id^="tab"]').each(..`.

Comment: also need to fix query string format... should be `?param1=xx&param2=yy` format

Comment: Sorry, please see my update, good sir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$("a#tab1")` selects a **single** `<a>` element having ID as `tab1`. To change the `href` attribute of a single element there is no need of `each`.

```
var href = $('a#tab1').attr('href') + '?startDate=20160121&endDate=20160212';
$('a#tab1').attr('href', href);
```

If having multiple elements with same ID, **ID should be unique.**

To select all the elements whose ID starts with `tab`, you can use [attribute start with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/). I'll suggest to use a unique class on them.

To change the `href` attribute value of all the matched elements [`.attr(attributeName, function)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) with callback function can be used.

```
$('a[id^="tab"]').attr('href', function(i, oldHref) {
    return oldHref + '?startDate=20160121&endDate=20160212';
});
```

---

As said by [@charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl) in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35679350/append-new-path-in-all-the-a-href-url/35679372#comment59036728_35679350), the querystring format should be as follow

```
'?startDate=20160121&endDate=20160212'
 ^                  ^
```

---

**Update:**

Saying again, **ID should be unique.**, you can use class instead of ID for similar purpose elements.

Change the markup to use class

```
<a class="tabopen" href="www.text.com/custom/questions/ask/">

<a class="tabopen" href="www.text.com/default/questions/ask/">
```

And then use the selector

```
$('.tabopen').something...
```

**BAD PRACTICE:**

If you can't change the markup(*auto-generated markup by some plugin*), you can use attribute value selector to select all elements having same ID

```
$('a[id="tabopen"]').something...
```