# jQuery - Replace contents of href="" with '#'

Tags: jquery

I need a way of replacing the text contained within `<a href="this text"` using jQuery, I want to replace what ever text is held within quotes to a `'#'`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery

Answer (score 15):

```
$('a').attr('href', '#');
```

Comment: Also notable: `$('a').attr('href')` actually *returns* whatever is inside the `href` attribute. jQuery has an awesome api, also: http://api.jquery.com

Comment: Be aware that this sample code will replace the `href` value of **all** links on your page, which is possibly not what the OP wants to do.  To narrow it down to a single element, use an ID selector instead - `$('#myLink').attr('href', '#');`.

Answer (score 7):

...

```
$(function(){
 $('a').attr('href', '#');
});
```

The `ready` handler should take care of changing the `href` of your links when the page loads.

If you have link(s) with some class or id set to them, you can simply do:

```
$(function(){
 $('a.link_class').attr('href', '#');
 // $('#some_id').attr('href', '#'); // for id
});
```

If you want to do it with some button click, etc, you can do like:

```
$('#button_id').click(function(){
  $('a').attr('href', '#');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This would be the simplest method:

```
$('a').attr('href', '#');
```

However if you have multiple  tags on your page you'll probably want an ID so you can single out a specific one to replace.

```
<a id='replaceme' href='...'></a>
```

If there's only a subset you want to rewrite, assign a class to them.

```
<a class='replaceme2' href='...'></a>
<a class='replaceme2' href='...'></a>
```

Then you could do the following:

```
$('#replaceme').attr('href', '#');  
//This will only replace the href for a single link
```

Or

```
$('.replaceme2').attr('href', '#');
//This will replace the href for all links with the replaceme2 class
```

Comment: “However if you have multiple tags on your page you'll probably want an ID so you can single it out.” IDs are supposed to be unique. Use `class`es instead.

Comment: That is exactly what I meant and why I gave the additional example of using classes.  I've updated the text of the answer to hopefully read more clearly.