# jQuery/Drupal Append string to all HREF on site (Any page)

Tags: php, jquery, drupal, href

So I have a site with a dozen pages on it using Drupal as a CMS. Wanted to know how to set/append all href links on any page with a dynamic attribute?

so here is an example URL:

```
http://www.site.com/?q=node/4
```

and I wanted to append to the URL like so:

```
http://www.site.com/?q=node/4&attr=1234
```

Now I have a nav bar on the site and when I hover over the link I see the url but I need to append the &attr=1234 string to the end of it. The string is dynamic so it might change from time to time.

I was thinking jQuery would be a good choice to do this but does Drupal have any functionality as well?

Now I've seen a couple of posts on Stack:

- [Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866341/jquery-replace-contents-of-href-with)
- [Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery)

Problem is I'm learning my way around Drupal and have minimal experience with jQuery but getting better with both. I see the jQuery can replace a HREF but looks like they hard coded the HREF, could jQuery find all HREF's on a page and append the string to it? Also does Drupal have this functionality and what would be the best approach?

Also need this to work for clean or standard URL format, so I think Apache would handle this I just wanted to make sure.

Thanks for any help

EDIT:

Looks like the general consensus is the Drupal should handle this type of request. Just looking for the best implementation. Simple function call would be best but I would like it to dynamically add it to all existing href's as I want this to be dynamic instead of hard coding any url/href calls. So I could add/remove pages on the fly without the need to reconfigure/recode anything.

Thanks for the great tips though

EDIT #2:

Okay maybe I'm asking the wring question. Here is what I need and why it's not working for me yet.

I need to pass a value in the url that changes some of the look and feel of the site. I need it to be passed on just about every href tag on the page but not on User logout or Admin pages.

I see in my template code where the nav links get generated, so I though I could pass my code in the attributes array as the second parm to the function, but that is setting the tag attributes and not the URL attributes.

Now I see the bottom nav links use this Drupal function: menu_navigation_links() in menu.inc but the top nav uses a custom function.

This function in the template.php script looks to be the one creating the links

```
function lplus($text, $path, $options = array()) {
  global $language;

  // Merge in defaults.
  $options += array(
      'attributes' => array(),
      'html' => FALSE,
    );

  // Append active class.
  if (($path == $_GET['q'] || ($path == '<front>' && drupal_is_front_page())) &&
      (empty($options['language']) || $options['language']->language == $language->language)) {
    if (isset($options['attributes']['class'])) {
      $options['attributes']['class'] .= ' active';
    }
    else {
      $options['attributes']['class'] = 'active';
    }
  }

  // Remove all HTML and PHP tags from a tooltip. For best performance, we act only
  // if a quick strpos() pre-check gave a suspicion (because strip_tags() is expensive).
  if (isset($options['attributes']['title']) && strpos($options['attributes']['title'], '<') !== FALSE) {
    $options['attributes']['title'] = strip_tags($options['attributes']['title']);
  }

  return '<a href="'. check_url(url($path, $options)) .'"'. drupal_attributes($options['attributes']) .'><b>'. ($options['html'] ? $text : check_plain($text)) .'</b></a>';
}
```

not sure how to incorporate what I need into this function.

So on the home page the ?q=node/ is missing and if I append the ampersand it throws an error.

```
http://www.site.com/&attr=1234 // throws error
```

But if I mod it to the correct format it works fine

```
http://www.site.com/?attr=1234
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929356/php-query-string-manipulation for function to manipulate the query string parameters of a URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that when you mean pages, you mean the content type of pages (will work for any other content type as long as it's really content and not something in a block or view).

You can easily replace the contents of any node that is about to be viewed by running a str_replace or with a regular expression.  For instance, using str_replace:

```
function module_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  switch($op) {
    case "view":
      $node->body = str_replace($expected_link, $desired_link);
      break;
  }
}
```

where you define desired link somewhere else.  Not an optimal solution, but non-Javascript browsers (yes, they still exist!) can't get around the forced, desired URLs if you try to change it with Javascript.

Comment: Thanks but this still looks like I need to pass in the href link, but I'm looking to do this dynamically as Drupal is already generating them.

Answer (score 1):

I think doing it in Drupal/PHP would be cleaner. Check out Pathauto module: http://drupal.org/node/17345

Comment: Thanks for the link but it looks like this is for aliasing, not sure if I understand how to implement this to append the href link. Could you explain a little more?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good discussion on a related topic here:
http://drupal.org/node/249864

This wouldn't use jquery (instead you would overwrite a function using PHP) but you could get the same result. This assumes, however, that you are working with menu links.

Comment: This seems like something I could use but it looks like you need to pass the link and value to the function. Drupal is already generating all the links, so how would I just append to those links?

Comment: It passes the link in automatically. Here is the drupal documentation: http://api.drupal.org/api/function/theme_menu_item_link/6

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider exploring PURL ( http://drupal.org/project/purl ) and some of the modules it works with e.g. spaces and context.

Comment: This does look like it would work but I only see it being use for clean URL's. Does it work with standard URL's as well?

Comment: I think so. Clean URLs are just cosmetically different. PURL should work fine with non-clean i.e. standard URLs

Answer (score 1):

I don't suggest you use jQuery to do this.   It's a better practice to do this server side in PHP (Drupal).
You can overwrite the links dynamically into your *preprocess page* function.

On your *template.php* file:

```
function *yourtheme*_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook){
  //You can do it for the region that you need
  $vars['content'] = preg_replace('/<a href="(.*?)"/i', '<a href="$1&attr=1234"', $vars['content']);
}
```

Note:

- I did not try it, its only a hint.
- It will add your parameters to the outside links too.

Comment: Thanks, I found the function in the template.php added and played with your code but no results. Any other tips?

Comment: sry it still doesn't work but I see what you're trying to do and I think this might work for me