# Change link to another link in Jquery

Tags: jquery

A site I am working on has links for add to cart I would like to change that link to point to different page how can I achieve this in jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //alert('Welcome to StarTrackr! Now no longer under police …');
    $("a[href='http://www.somesite.com/scAddItem.aspx?action=add&BJID=421&extra=type,journalIssue,volume,2,issue,<web::ISSUE>,npus,$99.00,npcdn,$99.00']").attr('href', 'http://www.live.com/');
});
```

I am trying this got this idea from here
 [How to change the href for a hyperlink using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery)
 but it's not working for me any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a selector with `*`:

```
$("a[href*='scAddItem']").attr('href', 'http://www.live.com/');
```

The links' `href` attribute will be changed for any link that contains `scAddItem` somewhere in its url. You can modify it for your exact string though.

**More Readings:**

- [XPath selectors](http://dev-tips.com/featured/jquery-tip-using-xpath-selectors)
- [attr method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: This is a good answer. I'm guessing the OPs problem is the selector is too specific and isn't returning the link. This should work IMO.

Answer (score 3):

i'd suggest adding an id to that link so you can reference it directly, much faster and simpler than trying to match on its href:

```
<a id="cartLink" href="/scAddItem.aspx?action=add&BJID=421&extra=type,journalIssue,volume,2,issue,,npus,$99.00,npcdn,$99.00">Add To Cart</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#cartLink").attr('href','http://www.live.com');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted looks right (although, I would give the `<a>` tag a ID attribute, so that you could avoid specifying the long search string.

```
<a id="MyLink" href='/scAddItem.aspx?action=add&BJID=421&extra=type,journalIssue,volume,2,issue,<web::ISSUE>,npus,$99.00,npcdn,$99.00'> text text text </a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $("#MyLink").attr('href', 'http://www.live.com/'); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: these anchors are generated by programming. there are so many other anchors I couldn't give all of them the same id

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("a[href='/scAddItem.aspx?action=add&BJID=421&extra=type,journalIssue,volume,2,issue,,npus,$99.00,npcdn,$99.00']").click(function() {
    $(this).attr('href', 'http://www.live.com/');
});
```

Or this if you could change your html.

```
$("a.mylink").click(function() {
    $(this).attr('href', 'http://www.live.com/');
});
```