# I need to update href value using jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to update href value thorughout the page using jquery.
Say href="http://www.google.com?gsec=account" should be changed to href="http://account.google.com?gsec=account" how i can get this done.

Comment: I assume you want a dynamic solution that searches the page, and does a replace instead of assigning a predetermined `href` to one predetermined `<a>` element. If so, I added an answer below that accomplishes that.

Comment: Hmm... I posted one assuming that "account" was a dynamic value, and that there may be other variations to the URL (e.g., http/https and other query string variables). I might have gone overboard after seeing your response though lol.

Comment: @jmar - Yeah, my answer does have a few requirements about what is replaced. A little tweak in the selector and in the `replace()` using a regex would open it up a little more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will do the replace *throughout* the page that I think you're looking for.

```
// Find `<a>` elements that contain `www.google.com` in the `href`.
$('a[href*="www.google.com"]').attr('href', function(i,href) {
       // return a version of the href that replaces "www." with "accounts."
    return href.replace('www.', 'accounts.');
});
```

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/dT8j6/

---

**EDIT:** This version allows for `https://` and for links without the `www.`.

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/dT8j6/1/

```
$('a[href*="google.com"]').attr('href', function(i,href) {
    return href.replace(/^http(s*):\/\/(www\.)*google.com/, 'http$1://accounts.google.com');
});
```

---

**EDIT:** If you only wanted to change elements that have `gsec=account`, then change the selector to `$('a[href*="gsec=account"]')`.

Comment: Won't this modify links to google that don't have the "gsec=account" param?

Comment: @jmar777 - Yes. I wasn't certain if that specific param was the requirement. Changing the selector to `$('a[href*="gsec=account"]')` would focus only on those elements.

Comment: Ya... which is probably 98% safe, but of course fails for yahoo.com?gsec=account, or gsec=accountfoo, etc. Not sure how _exact_ he needs this thing to be. Question is somewhat vague.

Comment: @jmar777 - Yes, I'm assuming OP controls the content of the href attributes. The selector can be as specific as OP needs. Could use `$('a[href$="google.com?gsec=account"]')` which adds `google.com` and uses the `ends-with` selector instead of `contains`. There will always be a way to break it if OP doesn't give specific requirements. :o)

Answer (score 3):

lets say you have this:

```
<a href="http://www.ibm.com" id="myLink">
```

you should use this:

```
 var newHref = "http://google.com";

 $("#myLink").attr('href', newHref );
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of:

[How to change the href for a hyperlink using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery)

One scenario it doesn't mention is if you set an id on your anchor that needs to be changed then you can use the id as a selector in jQuery.

```
$("#LinkId").attr('href', "http://account.google.com?gsec=account")
```

Answer (score 1):

This should hopefully provide a pretty full solution to your problem (as best I can interpret it, anyway):

```
$(function() {
  $('a').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      href = $this.attr('href');
    var res = href.match(/(.*?)(www)(\.google\.com.*?)([?&]gsec=)([^&]+)(.*)/);
    if (null != res) {
      // remove the "full match" entry
      res = res.slice(1);
      // replace www match with account match
      res[1] = res[4];
      // update the href attribute
      $this.attr('href', res.join(''))
    }
  });
});
```

---

*edit:* If "account" is a static value, then this will work as well:

```
$(function() {
  $('a').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      href = $this.attr('href');
    var res = href.match(/(.*?\/\/)(www)(\.google\.com.*?)([?&]gsec=account)(&?.*)/);
    if (null != res) {
      // remove the "full match" entry
      res = res.slice(1);
      // replace www match with account match
      res[1] = 'account';
      // update the href attribute
      $this.attr('href', res.join(''))
    }
  });
});
```

Please note that these solutions assume that there may be other variations in the URL, such as http/https and other query string variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think you left something out in your question. Nevertheless:

```
var link = $("a"); // Or some other selector to access the link
link.attr("href", "http://account.google.com?gsec=account");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery’s `.attr()` method. With one parameter, it returns the attribute value, with two parameters you set it.

```
$("a#whatever").attr("href", "http://account.google.com?gsec=account");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing all the links then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a").attr("href", "http://account.google.com?gsec=account");
});
```