# changing domain value of href using jquery

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I need to update href value using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459136/i-need-to-update-href-value-using-jquery)

I wanted to change the domain value of href using jquery.
If in the href="http://www.google.com?gsec=account" if i find gsec=account then i wanted to change only the domain value of href should be "http://account.google.com?gsec=account. There are other query string parameters which are added to gsec=account dynamically. So in the href whatever the value is i need to change only the domain name.

Comment: and this should via done via jquery rather than javascript because...?

Comment: is "account" a static value, or does that vary from account to account?  And you have several of us already helping you on this same question over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459136/i-need-to-update-href-value-using-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

I've tried answering this one for you over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459136/i-need-to-update-href-value-using-jquery/3459346#3459346), so I'm not sure why you're re-asking this. There are several other good answers on your original request as well.