# jquery replace problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

Any ideas why this jquery is not working?

```
$("div.aboutText p a").each( function() {
    $(this).replace(' ', 'ert');
});
```

OK... so I have a link that looks something like this...

```
<a href="#">My Link</a>
```

And I want it to look something like this...

```
<a href="#">MyertLink</a>
```

Comment: replace can not be run on a jQuery object. What do you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to replace something in the text of the a tag use this:

```
$("div.aboutText p a").each( function() {
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace('/ /', 'ert'));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

.replace() is a string method - it won't work on a jQuery object. Try:

```
$(this).text($(this).text().replace(" ", "ert"))
```

Comment: $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/ /gi, 'ert')); - this replaces every occurrence of a space. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should replace `text` or `html`:

```
$(this).html($(this).html().replace(" ", "ert"));
```

Or:

```
$(this).text($(this).text().replace(" ", "ert"));
```

---

To actually replace all instances of space, you will have to use regex with `/g` modifier like this:

```
$(this).text($(this).text().replace(/' '/g, 'ert'));
```

Another method would be using `split` and `join` like this:

```
$(this).text($(this).text().split(' ').join('ert'));
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure .text() returns by value, so this won't actually set the text

Answer (score 1):

`.replace()` is a plain Javascript method, it's not encapsulated by jQuery. So I guess you want to replace either the `text()` or the `href` value from your anchors.

```
$("div.aboutText p a").each( function() {
    $(this).text(function(i, text) {
        return text.replace(' ', 'ert');
    });
});
```

or

```
$("div.aboutText p a").each( function() {
    $(this).attr('href', (function(i, href) {
        return href.replace(' ', 'ert');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look here: [How to change the href for a hyperlink using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

What you want might be this instead:

```
$("div.aboutText p a").each(function() {
  var t = $(this).text().replace(" ","ert");
  $(this).text(t);
});
```

$(this) will return the a tag, but what part of the A tag are you trying to replace? the text?