# How to unbind a hyperlink with jQuery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

Is it possible to unbind the default behavior of a hyperlink?

I've learned from other questions that unbind can only be used on functions being bound with jQuery. I guess this could be the reason for it not working.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tim86/PRkwC/)

Comment: do you mean the href attribute?
see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prevent the default behavior using [`event.preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault), or by returning `false` from an event handler.

```
$('#some-link-id').click(function (event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
});

// or

$('#some-link-id').click(function ()
{
    return false;
});
```

***[Demo →](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/5kG9a/)***

As you suspected, you cannot use `unbind()` because there is no listener to unbind.

Answer (score 3):

`$('myDiv').unbind('click')` - if it was hooked up via JavaScript

`$('myDiv').attr('onclick','')` - if it has an inline event

`$('myDiv').attr('href','javascript://')` - creates a dummy link that does nothing

Comment: I don't think that removing an `onclick` attribute also removes the listener.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#buttonId").click(function() { return false; });
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try to bind all event types to it and use event.preventDefault() to stop default behavior something like this:

```
$('a').bind('touchstart touchmove touchend mousedown click mouseup select',function(e){
e.preventDefault()
})
```