# How to append variable to url in jquery?

Tags: jquery, url, attributes, append, href

How can I append `variable/text` to the attribute `href` in jquery ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function:

```
var foo = 'foo=bar';
$('a#foo').attr('href', function(index, attr) {
    return attr + '?' + foo;
});
```

or:

```
$('a#foo').attr('href', function() {
    return this.href + '?' + foo;
});
```

Comment: This doesn't take into consideration what the existing url is

Comment: This will break urls which already have a querystring. Have a look at @JohnC's answer.

Answer (score 10):

You need to check if there is already a query string before appending items to the url based on the other examples you'd do something like.

```
var foo = 'foo=bar';
$('a').attr('href', function(index, attr) {
    return attr + (attr.indexOf('?') >=0 ? '&' : '?') + foo;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a').attr('href', function(i, v) {
    return v + 'text...';
});
```

Comment: @Steffi The index of the element inside the jQuery object - irrelevant in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you use it repeatedly try .attr() as:

```
HTML: <a id='foo' href='#'>I am your father,.. nooooo</a>

var myparams = 'myvar=myvalue';
var myurl = 'TypeThe_NetscapeURL';
$('a#foo').attr('href', function() {
    return myurl + '?' + myparams;
});
```

Comment: Couple of comments: 1.that would work but it's actually overriding the value NOT appending. To append, get the value first $("#foo").attr('href') and then append whatever you need to it. 2. in example above you don't need a function which returns url. simple myurl+'?'+myparams should do it.  This is a case of taking a url and appending to it. Setting it to an href is just a byproduct. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery for setting hrefs