# How to provide hyperlinks to the dynamically generated elements through JQuery?

Tags: jquery

Actually i wanted to generate images dynamically with hyperlinks through jquery which is appended in `<div id='data'></div>`.

Through this code now i am able to create images but i am not getting idea to provide hyperlinks to the generated images. Just for the sake of simplicity, here I have inserted only a single image.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('#gallery h3').click(function(){{
$('<img></img>')
.attr('src', 'photo.jpg')
.hide()
.load(function() {
    $(this).fadeIn(4000);
    })
.appendTo($('#data'));
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='gallery'>
<h3 id='gdata'><a href='#'>Browsers</a></h3>
<div id='data'></div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$('<img></img>').attr('src', 'photo.jpg')
```

With:

```
$('<a href="something"><img src="photo.jpg" alt="something useful" \/><\/a>');
```

Comment: Thanks..Now the code is working as per your suggestion but only when the `hide()` is removed. but if `hide()` is removed then while loading the image, at first it is displayed at a position below `<div id='data'></div>` and then it is displayed at exact position as i have also used a preloader before displaying images.

Answer (score 0):

Check jQuery `live()` method
http://api.jquery.com/live/

May be this will be helpful
[How to change the href for a hyperlink using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery)