# How can I get the URL of a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the URL of a link?

```
$('.l').eq(0).href
```

is what I want to do, but it's undefined.

---

So given a jQuery selected anchor element, how do you get the href property?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery

Comment: Anchor elements don't have an href attribute, links do.

Comment: NO! You don't know and you are asking. Why could be stupid?

Comment: Just image you have this: `<h1 class="l">Foo</h1>`. Would the question make sense? That's why you need to post your HTML.

Comment: @RobG, excuse me, could you proof your statement with some links to W3C?

Comment: Fill yer boots: [HTML attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/index/attributes.html). href applies to A, AREA, LINK, BASE. Read the specification for an [A element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-A). In short, an A with a href is a link. An A with no href and a name or id is an anchor. Also [DOM 2 HTML anchors](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-7577272) collecton and [links collection](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-7068919).

Comment: Lastly, there's the [HTMLAnchorElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-48250443) and [HTMLLinkElements](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-35143001).If it has an *href* that links to a resource, it's a link. If it has a *name* that's the target of a link, it's an anchor. It can have both *name* and *href* and so be both an anchor and a link. The OP is after links.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.l').eq(0).attr("href")
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're selecting the link? Because I'm trying this in my site and ir works just fine:

```
    $('#id')[0].href
```

I mean, are you sure the $('.l').eq(0) part is working?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for

`$('.1 a')[0].href`