# changing the href or removing the onclick for a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, href, buttonclick

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('btnContinuePhone','')" class="button-hpo blue-button-23" id="btnContinuePhone" onclick="javascript:return ConfirmModalPopUp('phone');"><span>Next</span></a>
```

I want to change the href of this button and also removing on click. Could anybody tells me how to do it in jquery?

Comment: <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('btnContinuePhone','')" class="button-hpo blue-button-23" id="btnContinuePhone" onclick="javascript:return ConfirmModalPopUp('phone');"><span>Next</span></a>..this is code for button..

Comment: Related post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery

Comment: This suspiciously looks like ASP.NET code. Why not just remove it in your c#/vb code in the first place? Also, `onclick="javascript:…"` is wrong, onclick can only take javascript code, so it's unnecessary to add the javascript pseudo protocol

Comment: Thank you!I should need to do in javascript or jquery..

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
var el = $("#element");
if (el){
    el.unbind("click");
    el.attr("href", "newpage.htm");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo attached: http://jsfiddle.net/xavi3r/DQ4Sn/

```
$('#btnContinuePhone').click(function(){
   return false; 
});
$('#btnContinuePhone').attr('href','http://newurl.com');
```

Comment: Won't that simply add a second click event, rather than unbinding an existing one? See here for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery

Comment: Actually one popup will come when i click on next button. I don't want that popup to come, I want to go to next page without coming popup. Thought of changing href,or deleting the onclick. Both did not work. Any help i appreciated.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution :

```
$('#btnContinuePhone').attr('href', 'what ever you like');
$('#btnContinuePhone').click(function(){ return false;});
```

Or you can do that alternativly:

```
$('#btnContinuePhone').attr('href', 'what ever you like');
$('#btnContinuePhone').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
```

Comment: this has href:"javascript:__doPostBack('btnContinuePhone','')"..will it work??

Comment: Actually one popup will come when i click on next button. I don't want that popup to come, I want to go to next page without coming popup. Thought of changing href,or deleting the onclick. Both did not work. Any help i appreciated.Thanks!