# make hyperlink from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use a hyperlink string in HTML page which I want to declare source link (URL) in my js file. Please tell me how can I call that URL from my js into html.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of different ways to do this. You could use [document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement) to create a link element, and then inject the element into the DOM. Or you could use the `.innerHTML` property of an element that you already have on the page to insert the link using text. Or you could modify the "href" attribute of an existing link on the page. All of these are possibilities. Here is one example:

**Creating/Inserting DOM Nodes with DOM Methods**

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.textContent = 'Link Title';
link.href = 'http://your.domain.tld/some/path';
document.getElementById('where_to_insert').appendChild(link);
```

Assuming you have something like this in your HTML:

```
 <span id="where_to_insert"></span>
```

**Creating/Inserting DOM Content with innerHTML**

And another example using `innerHTML` (which you should generally avoid using for security reasons, but which is valid to use in cases where you completely control the HTML being injected):

```
 var where = document.getElementById('where_to_insert');
 where.innerHTML = '<a href="http://your.domain.tld">Link Title</a>';
```

**Updating the Attributes of a Named DOM Node**

Lastly, there is the method that merely updates the href attribute of an existing link:

```
 document.getElementById('link_to_update').href = 'http://your.domain.tld/path';
```

... this assumes you have something like the following in your HTML:

```
 <a id="link_to_update" href="javascript:void(0)">Link Title</a>
```

Comment: Thanks to all, but the problem is I have declare the URL in js file and the text link in html page, while clicking on that link in html that links to the js file URL.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var alink = document.createElement("a");
alink.href = "http://www.google.com";
alink.text = "Test Link";
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(alink)
```

Answer (score 0):

From whatever I understand, You want to update `href` with JS variable. 
You can use Jquery to achieve it. 
try `$("a").attr("href", js_variable)`
Refer this for more details 
[How to change the href for a hyperlink using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you would be able to do something like this:

**Using Javascript.**

```
var col2= document.getElementById('id_Of_Control');
col2.innerHTML="<a href='page2.html?" + params + "'>Page 2</a>";
```

where `col2` is another container control something like `div`,`span`, or any.

**Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com).**

Here I will recommend you to Use jQuery. So you can be more dynamic.

```
 $("#col2").append("<a href='page2.html?" + params + ">Page 2</a>");
```

OR

```
$("#col2").after("<a href='page2.html?" + params + ">Page 2</a>");
```

OR

```
$("#col2").before("<a href='page2.html?" + params + ">Page 2</a>");
```