# Inserting HTML Into Document Body Hangs

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

I'm trying to insert HTML into the body of a web page using NightmareJS. I'm using the following code to work within the document scope:

```
await nightmare.evaluate(function(users) {
        for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            var matchResult = users[i].match(/.com\/(.*?)\?fref/);
            if (matchResult) {
                document.body.innerHTML += '<a href="https://www.example.com/'+matchResult[0]+'">'+matchResult[0]+'</a>';
            }
        }
    }, users);
console.log("we got here");
```

The `console.log` never happens. Instead I get:

```
Error: Evaluation timed out after 30000msec.  Are you calling done() or resolving your promises?
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/user/www/project/bin/scraper/node_modules/nightmare/lib/actions.js:509:10)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:469:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:304:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:264:5)
```

If I remove the `innerHTML` line, it executes fine and I can return values from `matchResult`. What's wrong here?

Edit: Here are related issues:

https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/759

https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/688#issuecomment-238473332

https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/pull/819

https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/759

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to createElement('a'), define the text, then add the link *only* with innerHTML. There's a similar question here: [make hyperlink from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005694/make-hyperlink-from-javascript) , assuming that you want to create a new element.

Comment: I don't think that's it. I think it's evaluate timing out. I have added more info to the question.

Comment: I actually got it done with `appendChild`, a similar solution to what you provided.