# Can I create a link in a SCORM package with a querystring parameter of the value from the runtime?

Tags: scorm, scorm1.2

Is it possible when creating SCORM packages to insert a link into the package at design time which would have it's url built up from values in the runtime, cmi.core.student_id for example? Or any other custom values only known at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming you are able to write Javascript into the content and have it manipulate the DOM at runtime.

SCORM has an API you can access with Javascript in your content. You would get the API reference, then make the call to LMSGetValue('cmi.core.student_id'), then build the URL and put it on the page by adding it to the DOM. See: [SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8005773/1187723) for more info.

There's some references here at [ADL](https://adlnet.gov/past-projects/scorm/#scorm-versions-and-resources).

You can find some SCORM 1.2 Wrappers out there, which are JS files that connect to the SCORM API for you and give you functions to talk to the API. They aren't absolutely necessary but they are helpful.

Comment: Yeah thanks Tom that's the way I was heading, unfortunately it appears we can't write Javascript in the content with our authoring tool.

Comment: Hmm.. some tools do give you a set of variables you can use in your content but I'm out of my expertise at this point. I wish you the best of luck.