# Change href value  for a hyperlink

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the href for a hyperlink using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery)

I have a link that is being generated by a database that I need to change.

I was wondering if I can use jQuery to find the required id and change the href value?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Sure:

```
$("#linkId").attr("href", "http://the.new.url");
```

Answer (score 16):

If your HTML was like this:

```
<a href="xxx" id="myLink">whatever</a>
```

You can change the link by doing this in plain javascript:

```
document.getElementById("myLink").href = "http://whatever.com/yyyy";
```

Or, using jQuery:

```
$("#myLink").attr("href", "http://whatever.com/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#id_of_link").attr("href", "/new/url");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this when the page loads, use the following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#linkId").attr("href", "http://the.new.url");

});
```