# replace html attribute using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html

```
<div class="pic">
     <a class="shutterset_publication-workshop" title="" href="http://localhost/639.jpg">
    <img src="http://localhost/researchclub/yu.jpg" alt="copy-of-dsc03639">
     </a>
</div>
```

The problem is that i want to replace the 'href' attribute of the anchor tag using jquery while preserving the img element using jquery, but have failed.

`$(".pic a['href']").replaceWith("<a>")` is not working.

Comment: "is not working" is not a description of the observed vs expected behaviour, "[I] [h]ave failed" is a lovely story, and there is no question about a programming language here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the href for a hyperlink using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

The short version:

```
$("a.shutterset_publication-workshop").attr("href", "the new value");
```

or

```
$(".pic a.shutterset_publication-workshop").attr("href", "the new value");
```

or

```
$(".pic a").attr("href", "the new value");
```

The long version:

> ...but ave failed. `$(".pic a['href']").replaceWith("<a>")` is not working...

You're thinking in terms of markup. But the time the jQuery code is running, the markup is gone; instead, you have DOM elements (objects) in a tree structure in memory. You need to think in terms of finding the elements in the DOM (since you use jQuery, that would be with CSS selectors — and your selector was fine) and modifying their attributes/properties directly, not replacing them with new markup.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function to do this. There is no need to replace the element when you can modify it.

```
$(".pic a['href']").attr('href', 'http://google.com');
```