# Override anchor's href

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the href for a hyperlink using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery)

I have an anchor tag for which the href="" like so 
`<a class="SwitchAccountLink" href=""></a>`. I want to override this using jQuery and provide a different href. Is it possible to override the inline href of an anchor tag?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @undefined - forgot to initialize your username again? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jQuery's `.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function to modify specific attributes of your elements.

```
$("a.SwitchAccountLink").attr('href',NEW_URL);
```

This code will replace **all anchor tags with the `SwitchAccountLink` class** with `NEW_URL`.

If you want to only change specific links, you might have to provide a more unique `id` attribute or an additional class that groups all the links.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery `attr()` to get and set values of element attributes, more about [**attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) As your anchor tag has class which we will use to uniquely identify all the anchors with class `SwitchAccountLink`

```
$('.SwitchAccountLink').attr('href', 'Yourhref');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.SwitchAccountLink').attr('href', 'http://www.google.com');
```

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 1):

you can change it doing `$(".SwitchAccountLink").attr('href','myNewHref');`

Answer (score 1):

Sure, try:

```
$('.SwitchAccountLink').attr('href','someurl');
```