# Javascript dynamic change in link href

Tags: java, jquery, search, hyperlink, href

Is there a clear cut method to changing the contents of a url in href based on user submitted information?

For EXAMPLE: A user submits the word "basketball" into a search box and the result is the following link.

```
<a href="http://google.com/basketball>More information</a>
```

If the user submitted lets say "football" the link would then change to:

```
<a href="http://google.com/football>More information</a>
```

Comment: You can see the answer here... It's a duplicate question.... [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery)

Comment: because its a duplicate

[How to change the href for a hyperlink using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

You have missing close quote of href, You can do it this way.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YnMcJ/1/)**

```
var url = $('#aId').attr('href');
firstPart = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf('\/')+1);
$('#aId').attr('href', firstPart + "Football");
```

Answer (score 1):

Given:   `<a id="url" href="http://google.com/basketball">More information</a> 
          <input id="sport" type="text" val="soccer" />`

```
var $val = $('#sport').val()
$("#url").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/" + $val);
```