# Change the href link of an anchor with the text using jquery

Tags: jquery

if I have:

```
<a href="#">Title </a> 
<a href="#">Title2 </a>
```

I want on the first anchor the href to be Title and on the second one Title2

I've tried using the `attr("href" function() { return this.text; });`

Comment: Possbible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery

Answer (score 3):

Almost there :

```
$('a').attr("href", function() { return $(this).text(); });
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/BcNxB/)

Comment: +1, good use of using the second parameter as a function. (OP started with it, but I still wasn't aware `attr` worked like native `.replace` does with passing a function)

Comment: @BradChristie It's a jQuery thing, if you notice almost all of them are able to do this not just `attr`. You can even do it with CSS: `$('a').css('background', function () { **whatever** });`

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS: I don't disagree; and it's more like jQuery implemented it with the original methods like `replace` in mind to keep consistency.

Answer (score 1):

*Changing* it would be something like:

```
$('a').each(function(i,e){
  this.href = '#' + $(this).text(); // using # because i assume named anchor?
});
```

That would change:

```
<a href="#">Title</a>        -> <a href="#Title">Title1</a>
<a href="#">Title2</a>       -> <a href="#Title2">Title2</a>
```

- Grab all anchors (`$('a')`)
- Loop through each one (`.each()`)
- Assign a new value using the anchor's text (`this.href = $(this).text()`)

*You can also remove the `'#' +` portion from above if you don't want a link to a named anchor/id element, but chances are anything that's being supplied by the anchor's display text isn't going to be a valid URL)*