# Change link href via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the href for a hyperlink using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery)

I'm using Drupal and system generate my title.

E.G.

```
    <a class="jquery-once-3-processed" id="quicktabs-tab-galeri-1" 
href="/?q=node&amp;qt-galeri=1#qt-galeri">NEWS</a>
```

I want change this `href` link via jQuery. How can i do this? Thank you.

Comment: $("a#quicktabs-tab-galeri-1").attr("href", new_href); or $("a.jquery-once-3-processed").attr("href", new-href); both should do fine

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$("#quicktabs-tab-galeri-1").attr("href", new_href);
```

That should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#quicktabs-tab-galeri-1').attr('href', 'YOUR_NEW_HREF');
```

This selects the element with id *quicktabs-tab-galeri-1* and changes its *href* attribute.

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
$('#quicktabs-tab-galeri-1').attr("href", "http://yournewlink.com");
```