# Change specific tags in a div tag using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div tag:

```
<div id="content"><p></p><a href="#"></a></div>
```

I want to insert dynamically different content into the `<p>` tag and also into the **href** attribute of the `<a>` tag.

I am using jQuery.

Comment: The jQuery API documentation is pretty extensive. You should have a look at it some time: http://api.jquery.com/. A jQuery tutorial might be helpful as well: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery.

Comment: Partial duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/179713/218196

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As easy as:

```
$("#content > p").html("Some content");
$("#content > a").prop("href", "/new/link.html");
```

Or in chain:

```
$("#content")
  .find("p").html("Some content")
    .end()
      .find("a").prop("href", "/new/link.html");
```

Comment: Thanks! If I have 2 tags like <a href="#" class="blue one"></a><a href="#" class="red one"></a> how can I change only one of them?

Comment: @user550413 You [class selectors](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/): `$("#content a.blue").prop(...);`.

Comment: I tried it but because my class has spaces in it's name (I use it in css) it doesn't work.

Comment: @user550413 Class name can't have spaces. Spaces split different classes set to the element, i.e. `class="blue red"` means that element has both CSS classes `blue` and `red`.

Comment: I figured it out. Many Thanks!