# how can the value of an href attribute be changed using javascript/css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, styles

Assuming that the html contains the following structure:

```
<div>
    <a href="http://the/link/that/needs/to/be/changed">text</a>
</div>

<div>
    <div>
        //<script> or <style> must go here
    </div>
</div>
```

...and assuming that the 'contribution' to the final HTML file can be inserted ONLY at the specified location, and assuming that the markup for the "a" element cannot be modified in any way, is it possible to add javascript or css code that will change the url that the href attribute of the previous "a" element refers to? If so, how?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery

Comment: If you want to get the previous `a` element and cannot change the HTML, this should do: `var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); var last = elements[elements.length - 1];`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it without id:

```
document.querySelector("a[href^='http://the']")
```

and set the href prop:

```
document.querySelector("a[href^='http://the']").href=whatever
```

For a full reference (browser-compatibility) of `querySelector` see the [MDN-Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector)

Answer (score 2):

Put an id on it, e.g.

```
<a id="the_a_tag" href="...">...</a>
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

then the JS is simply

```
document.getElementById('the_a_tag').href = 'new address goes here';
```

as long as you put the javascript AFTER the relevant HTML.

And note: CSS is for presentation only. With a few exceptions, it cannot affect the content of document elements, merely how they appear (color/size/position/etc...).

Comment: I have no control over the id of the "a" element.

Answer (score 1):

Give the link an id
`<a href='...' id='linkToChange'>text</a>`

And then access it in your script:
`document.getElementById('linkToChange').href='newAddress';`

Comment: I have no control over the id of the "a" element.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using something like this:

```
document.getElementById("abc").href="xyz.php";
```

You will need to set an ID for the  tag, so your tag will look like this:

```
    <div>
    <a href="http://the/link/that/needs/to/be/changed">text</a>
</div>

<div>
    <div>
        //<script> or <style> must go here
    </div>
</div>
```