# add parameters to anchor tag via javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add parameters to anchor tag via JavaScript. I do not want to use jQuery for this purpose. Here is my html anchor tag

```
<div class="u-right u-half"><a href="http://example.com/register/" class="u-button u-alt">Register</a></div>
```

I am able to do this with jquery but I want to do this with JavaScript. Here is my jquery but I want to use JavaScript instead

```
jQuery('.u-right .u-button').attr("href", function(i, href) {
return href + '?page=search';
});
```

How I can do this with JavaScript ?

Answer (score 3):

```js
document.getElementById("placeholder").href += '?page=search';
```

```html
<div class="u-right u-half" id="placeholder">
  <a href="http://example.com/register/" class="u-button u-alt">Register</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You should avoid answering duplicate questions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155135/how-can-the-value-of-an-href-attribute-be-changed-using-javascript-css

Comment: Yup @AnkitAgarwal I didn't Observed that!!

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have tried this code but it is causing an error. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'href' of null. Why it is causing this error.

Comment: had you added id="placeholder" into your element? @Awan.

Comment: No I did not, Actually I am using document.querySelector('.u-right .u-button').href += '?page=search';

Comment: I have fixed this issue and for this I added document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ 
});
around my code and now it is working perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Using `getElementsByClassName()` and `setAttribute()` you can do like below

```js
var anchor = document.getElementsByClassName('u-button')[0];
anchor.setAttribute('href', anchor + '?page=search')

console.log(anchor);
```

```html
<div class="u-right u-half"><a href="http://example.com/register/" class="u-button u-alt">Register</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make that happen for all anchors/elements that match some css selector:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('.u-right .u-button')]
  .forEach(node => node.href += '?page=search')
```

Old School js:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(…))
  .forEach(function (node) { … });
```