# How to disable or delete an href link dynamically on longpressevent in jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can anyone help me to convert an href link to normal text on long press, to enable it for editing on some button click event and to remove it completely in case after editing there is no text. These hyperlinks are generated dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

search for http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/ to remove the hyperlink
href edit/status [How to change the href for a hyperlink using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery)