# get selected value of Select Control in Asp.net MVC razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, select, anchor

I have defined an select on top of my page which shows pageSize(item list pr page)

```
        <select name="ddlPageSize" style="text-align:left;width:80px;">
        @for (var i = 5; i <= 100; i=i+5){

             <option>@i</option>
        }
        </select>
```

now when i wants to set page size in pagging link like.

```
 <div style="width:inherit; padding:15px 0; clear:both;">
    <ul style="text-align:center">

        @for (int i = 0; i < (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)totalCount / (decimal)pageSize); i++)
        {        
            int page = i + 1;
            string background = "transparent";//transparent
            if (pageNo == page)
            {
               background = "grey";
            }

            <li style="display:inline; font-size:14px; color:#000; font-weight:bold; font-family:'VAGRound';padding:0 0px; background-color:@background; ">

                 <a href="~/Admin/Userspagging?page=@page">@page</a>

            </li>
        }
        </ul>
    </div>
```

in html anchor i wants to pass selected page size too with page Number

```
<a href="~/Admin/Userspagging?page=@page & size=@pageSize">@page</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change the url on `ddlPageSize` selected index change in jQuery.
Here is a link for the same
[How to change the href for a hyperlink using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery)

First of all add some class over your `anchor` so that you can easily get your Item in jQuery as.

```
 <a class='apager' href="~/Admin/Userspagging?page=@page">@page</a>
```

and use jquery as below

```
$("#ddlPageSize" ).on("change", function() {
   var selectedValue=$(this).val();
   $(".apager").each(function(item,index){
       item.attr("href",item.attr("href")+"&pageSize="+selectedValue);
   });

});
```

**Note that** this is just an idea not implemented so far.

Comment: this idea helps me alot
thanks for jquery hint and idea

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update the anchor link based on user selection, it will have to be done client side.

Also use the data attributes for the URL.  You know you will update the URL with just the current page.

```
<a id="LINKID" data-url="~/Admin/Userspagging?page=@page" href="">@page</a>
```

Attach a function to the change event of the dropdown.

```
$("#ddlPageSize" ).on( "change", function() {

   $("#LINKID").attr("href", $("#LINKID").data("id") + "&size=" + $("#ddlPageSize").val())

});
```

something like that...