# change link href attribute with html() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

If i have a link in my page.I want to change its href attribute after some event is triggered how i can do that

**Button**

`<a id="btn-start" href="/dashboard/save/{{ pk }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-embossed">Save Reward</a>`

Javascript

```
$( "#sortable1 div" ).sortable({
        connectWith: "div",
        stop: function( event, ui ) {

            if($('#sortable2').find('img').length==6) {
                $('#btn-start').html("<a id='btn-start' href='/dashboard/redeem/{{ pk }}' class='btn btn-danger' >Redeem Coupon</a>");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`html()` will change the **inner HTML** of your element. As a result, your code adds another `<a>` element inside your `#btn-start` element.

You can use the [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) function to change the actually HTML property (and attribute):

```
if($('#sortable2').find('img').length == 6) 
{
    $('#btn-start').prop('href', '/dashboard/redeem/{{ pk }}');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#btn-start').attr ('href', "http://sample");
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code you change href,class and innerhtml of "#btn-start".If its below is the working code

```
 $('#btn-start').attr('href=','/dashboard/redeem/{{ pk }}')
 .attr('class','btn btn-danger').html('Redeem Coupon');
```