# Changin href value with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, href

I have the following test html:

```
<div class="resultsFooter">
    <ul id="ResultFooter">
        <li id="Preferences">
            <a title="Preferences" id="PreferenceLink" href="http://google.com">Preferences</a>
        </li>
        <li id="Advanced">
            <a title="Advanced" id="AdvancedLink" href="http://ask.com">Advanced</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to change the href value of the second a link from "http://ask.com" to "http://bing.com" using jquery. I have the below jquery but it does not seem to do trick, I am missing something in the selector:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('a#AdvancedLink').attr('href', 'http://www.bing.com');

});
```

Any suggestion on this would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a note, no need to put the tag name before the id of your element. Since IDs are always unique it is unnecessary.

Comment: Your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/A9TXL.

Comment: Cant be very simple selector like `$('#AdvancedLink')`, since ids are unique

Comment: However, your code is correct and it should work as it is.

Comment: Maybe a problem due to your jQuery version. Did you try prop('href','http/bing.com') instead of attr(...) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery

Comment: @John Conde - I did try this out on jsfiddle before and could have swore it was not working. But thanks for checking, have clicked your jsfiddle link and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original code works fine, however you can remove the `a` from the selector since the `ID` should be unique:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#AdvancedLink').attr('href', 'http://www.bing.com');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S2NkH/

If you inspect the markup in the JSFiddle, you can see that `Advanced` has the `href` value set to bing.com

Comment: What if the same JavaScript file was included on two pages with `#AdvancedLink` elements, but only one of them was an `a` element? :) (Wasn't me who downvoted, in case you're wondering).

Comment: @JamesDonnelly - I would question the developer who named the element `AdvancedLink` if it was not referring to anchor/`hyperlink` element.

Answer (score 0):

its being an id(unique) you can directly refer it only by that id

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#AdvancedLink').attr('href', 'http://www.bing.com');

});
```