# How to append to an element and set text for multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of elements where I want to create list like structure with the Bootstrap element (example):

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">List group item heading</h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">...</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

I figured that I will do something like:

```
foreach(element)
{
   $("#ul").append($("<a href='" + element +"'>").text(element));
}


<div class="container">
  <div id="ul" class="list-group">
</div>
```

This works fine but I am not sure how to do the other nested elements (`<h4>` and `<p>`) and also set their `text` property. Also is there a cleaner way to do the `href` part of `<a>` element ? Any hints and tips are appreciated.

Comment: There is no `foreach` keyword in JavaScript.

Comment: @Vohuman I used that as a shortcut just to describe my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build those elements individually and append them after you've already operated on them:

```
foreach(element)
{
  var anchor = $("<a href='" + element +"'>");
  var header = $('<h4>').text('stuff');
  var p = $('<p>').text('More stuff');
  anchor.append(header).append(p);
  $("#ul").append(anchor);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as the main question goes, Brennan's answer will definitely do the trick. As for another way to do the href in your `<a>`, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery).