# jquery - Replace part of a URL link with other text

Tags: jquery

with jQuery, 
if I have the following link....

```
http://msite.com/stuff/default.aspx?var=9892372
http://msite.com/stuff/default.aspx?var=98sdk73
http://msite.com/stuff/default.aspx?var=89378ch
http://msite.com/stuff/default.aspx?var=1383409
```

...how can I change the begining part so that it reads...

```
http://showmesomethingdifferent.com/stuff/default.aspx?var=xxx
```

for any link that has this original format?

FYI - any of these links can be referenced from

```
$('#manage ul li a')....
```

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
url = url.replace("msite", "showmesomethingdifferent");
```

And for each link...

```
$('#manage ul li a').each(function(){
this.href = this.href.replace("msite", "showmesomethingdifferent");
});
```