# Replace a "href" element with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have such code:

```
    <li class="myClass">
        <a href="www.example.com">link</a>
    </li>
```

I need to change href attribute to www.example2.com
How would I achieve that using javascript?

Comment: If you want to change the `href` attribute of *multiple* elements, see this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/28016553/2680216

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `document.querySelector`:

```
document.querySelector('.myClass a').href = 'www.example2.com'
```

Javascript was originally designed to access the DOM on websites, so you would need to *find* the element within `document`. There are a bunch of ways to do it. Check out all the methods that start with "get" here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp.

Comment: that was fast, and worked great:) thanks