# replace href value in dom variable

Tags: jquery

```
var dstr='<p id="para">&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo<a href="#table1(t1)" id="ytD2F">table1</a> test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo <a href="#table2(t2)" id="ytD2F">table2</a>&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;</p>';
```

i have to find all href attribute in which "table" string should be present eg:href="#table1(t1)" and then i have to replace it with the string present in braces  eg:href="t1"

Comment: what you expect hmmm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you need this:

```
var re = /(#table\d+)|\((\w{1,2})(\))/g; 
var str = '<p id="para">&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo<a href="#table1(t1)" id="ytD2F">table1</a> test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo <a href="#table2(t2)" id="ytD2F">table2</a>&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;demo test&nbsp;</p>';
var subst = '$2'; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
console.log(result);
```

Regex101 demo: https://regex101.com/r/uP6uY7/1

Comment: hey thankcx yr answer was just perfect its solves my problem

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps:

```
var href1=document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(i=0;i<href1.length;i++) {
   var val=href1[i].getAttribute('href');
   if(val!=null && val.indexOf("table")>=0) {
     var str=val.substring(val.lastIndexOf('(')+1,val.lastIndexOf(')'));
     href[i].setAttribute('href',str);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a way to do it:

```
$init = $('a[href*="table"]').attr('href');
        $('a[href*="table"]').attr('href',$init.substring($init.lastIndexOf('(')+1,$init.lastIndexOf(')')));
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vxpyyy15/3/

Comment: you should test this code, it has multiple problems

Comment: Still doesn't make sense what your replace is doing and it won't change individual `href` it will make them all the same based on first one found

Comment: change the question change the answer