# Replacing a href link using jQuery .attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I'm trying to change the content of a href using jQuery. I've found a number of good answers on this site, and am trying to use this one to implement it:

[How to change the href for a hyperlink using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery)

I have it wrapped in an if statement like this:

```
if(window.location.href == "http://test.com/Home.aspx"){

    $("a[href='https://www.surveymonkey.com/s/tester123']").attr('href', 'https://www.surveymonkey.com/s/tester234');
}
```

I've put some console logs in place and they show that this line of code is being reached, and that this:

```
$("a[href='https://www.surveymonkey.com/s/tester123']")
```

Is returning the correct link. However the href value is never replaced when I check the page source.

I'm using http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js?build=7111092

I'm a bit stuck on how to debug what the issue is, can anyone help spot it? Hopefully its just a stupid mistake!

--EDIT--

I have now also checked it using inspect element and it's not been replaced unfortunately.

Also thanks to @Vohuman and @roxxypoxxy for the info on not being able to see the change unless I hovered over it. Stupidly I was expecting it to work like a find/replace!

Comment: "However the href value is never replaced when I check the page source.". You should inspect the element and see the live representation of the DOM elements.

Comment: The page source is the page source, you cannot change it (fortunately) client side...

Comment: I've just checked it by inspecting the element and it's still the same unfortunately.

Comment: @hollie3406 Then please provide minimalistic sample to replicate issue

Comment: The page source can never be changed by the DOM manipulation done by the javascript. To validate your href replacement is working, you can hover over your link and see in the status bar the link it is pointing.

Comment: @A.Wolff what do you mean sorry?

Comment: @hollie3406 Provide enough code in question itself  to replicate your issue

Comment: here's a jsfiddle for this https://jsfiddle.net/3vaqn2qt/1/ I added the same version of jquery provided under external resources and it works correctly you can hover on link to shows it display href ends with `tester234 `

Comment: You could have also simply done `$("a[href='https://www.surveymonkey.com/s/tester123']")[0].href =  'https://www.surveymonkey.com/s/tester234';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is a Jquery version issue. You are using Jquery 1.5. In Jquery docs they have mentioned this

> Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes took property values
>   into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause
>   inconsistent behavior.

Source https://api.jquery.com/attr/

So try to use higher JQuery version or use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

Comment: This has just solved it - thank you! Will accept as correct answer when the time is up.