# How to change anchor's href attribute value on click

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using the following code to link to a section on a page.

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (event) {
    var target = $(this.href);
    if (target.length) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
});


<a href="#group1" class="save">Save 20%</a>
```

The link is positioned absolute on the bottom right of the screen; 
Is there a way I can change the link on click?  So that When you Click `<a href="#group1"` It scrolls to that section and then the same link becomes `#group2,` and then becomes `#group3`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the href for a hyperlink using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/07heubgc/) should do the trick.

I grabbed the current href value, incremented it by one and replaced it:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (event) {
    var target = $(this.href);
    if (target.length) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
    var idx = $(this).attr('href').slice(6);
    var newIdx = (idx)%3+1;
    $(this).attr("href",'#group'+newIdx);
});
```

You can see on mouseover that the link is changing (you have to move off and back on to see the change in most browsers).

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU! I can't upvote because of reputation but this did what I needed! thank you so much!

Comment: how would i add the slow scroll back into it? I can't get that to work properly. sorry for the trouble!

Comment: I added that back in (but not in the fiddle, since I don't have your whole page).  I think you should be able to upvote and mark your own question answers as correct - I didn't think that was a restricted privilege.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-href="#group1" class="save">Save 20%</a>

<div id="group1"></div>
<div id="group2"></div>
<div id="group3"></div>
```

JS

```
var i=1;
$('a').on('click', function (event) {
    i++;
    var anchor = $(event.target);
    var target = $($(event.target).data("href"));
    console.log(target);
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
    anchor.data("href","#group"+i);
});
```

Answer working live on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rLpez4sp/1/

You can check the Javascript console for the link change.