# Javascript change link destination

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a javascript that goes makes `<a>` go to another link, rather than the one specified in its href. E.g. I want

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/some-page">
```

To go to instead:

```
http://www.newexamplesite.com/http:%252F%252Fwww.example.com%252Fsome-page
```

Unfortunately I don't have access to jQuery for this application. Has to be pure javascript.

I'm looking for some javascript that can be included within the actual `<a>` tag:

```
<a onclick="" href="http://www.example.com/some-page">
```

> Note that the original link has to be detected and all `/` is needed
>   to be replaced with `%252F`

Comment: What is wrong with `<a href="http://www.newexamplesite.com/http:%252F%252Fwww.example.com%252Fsome-page">http://www.example.com/some-page</a>`? This way your users can also check the bottom of their browser so they know where they are actually going. You should not redirect users to a different site that you claim though.

Comment: I understand. But in this case I'm developing an API and in some cases webmasters may not have the knowledge to change their links using PHP on the server side.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28016553/2680216

Comment: That's jQuery. I can't guarantee that webmasters will be using that. And it's not ethical to force them to load jQuery just for something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a onclick="window.location.href = 'http://newlink.com/' + encodeURIComponent(this.href); return false;" href="http://www.example.com/some-page/">Go to new link</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to double-encode the forward slash. This is because the server prematurely decodes %2F to / and routes it to the wrong destination. By double-encoding to %252F I prevent that issue. I'm using it for GET applications.

Answer (score 0):

You should prevent a default event (i.e. going to the link specified by href) and go to another link.

```
<a onclick="event.preventDefault();location.href='http://www.newexamplesite.com/'+this.href.replace(/\//g,'%252F')"
   href="http://www.example.com/some-page">
   test
</a>
```

Comment: (Edited to add the "lookup for the original link")

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<a onclick="event.preventDefault();location.href='http://www.uol.com.br/'" href="http://www.example.com/some-page">Link Text</a>
```

The `event.preventDefault` should stop the anchor element's default behaivour (ie - directing the user to the site within the `a href`.

EDIT: forgot parentheses on function call!

Comment: I was typing my original answer as yours came up it would appear - I wouldn't post a duplicate answer on purpose. Thanks and fixed - forgot the parentheses on the preventDefault() function.

Comment: I agree that it should be preventDefault. There is a lookup of the original link though also to be made.

Answer (score -1):

You can replace the href URL with a function call like this:

```
<a href="javascript:goToLink()" />
<script>
 function goToLink(){
  // your link selection logic goes here
      .....

// when you have selected the link you want to go to assign it to the window location.href attribute and the browser will redirect the user to the specified link
window.location.href = "..selected link...";
}
</script>
```