# How can I get href to follow a link when using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I'm having trouble getting `<a href="#">` to follow the link when jQuery is activated.

```
<ul>
    <li class="menuOption"><a href="#"></a>Home</li>
    <li class="menuOption"><a href="#"></a>About</li>
</ul>
```

I looked at a few posts but they involve people trying to prevent a link being followed by using `preventDefaults();` in the .js file. I'm not sure what my solution would be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the href for a hyperlink using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery)

Comment: To follow which link? There are no links

Comment: Does it work when jQuery is not activated?

Comment: can you give us an example of what you are looking for?

Comment: i just had another try. It doesn't work when jQuery is not activated. It doesn't work period. (having substituted the '#' with https://www.google.com)
-it appears its not being viewed as a hyperlink. just plain text

Comment: Try putting something in your anchors. There's nothing to click on right now. Perhaps you meant to wrap the text inside the a tags.

Comment: @vitamike You meant to write `<li class="menuOption"><a href="#">Home</a></li>` String needs to be inside the <a></a> tags.

Comment: @MasNotsram thanks-- I'm wholeheartedly embarrassed by the solution, but that was it.

Answer (score 3):

You Need to put the link text inside of the anchor tags. Right now, the a tag is empty and so therefore un-clickable.

Try this instead:

```
<ul>
    <li class="menuOption"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="menuOption"><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple ways to accomplish this :- 
1. One way is to change your href to point to javascript:void(0) rather than #
so the code should be

```
  <ul>
      <li class="menuOption"><a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>Home</li>
       <li class="menuOption"><a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>About</li>
  </ul>
```

You must also return false from your jquery function if you have some url written and onclick is present

```
 <ul>
          <li class="menuOption"><a href="www.google.com" onclick="somefun)()"></a>Home</li>
      </ul>
```

Dont forgot to return false from your function
     function somefun(){
     return false; 
     }

Comment: Thanks the solution was as @MasNotsram stated above. Syntactic error