# How to set the href parameter value using javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following form,

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="language">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Language:</td>
                <td>
                    <form:select path="languageName" id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
                        <form:option value="" label="...." />
                        <form:options items="${languages}" />
                    </form:select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:errors path="languageName" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;" />
                </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a id="demo" href="/eidsar/openid-authn-request?type=ident&lang=">OpenID 2.0 Identification</a> <br>
                    <a href="/eidsar/openid-authn-request?type=auth&lang=">OpenID 2.0 Authentication</a> <br>
                    <a href="/eidsar/openid-authn-request?type=auth-ident&lang=">OpenID 2.0 Identification and Authentication</a> <br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
```

I would like to change the value of lang whenever the dropdown value is selected,

Here is my javascript function,

```
<script>
        function myFunction(val) {
            /* var text = document.getElementById("demo").getAttribute("href")+val;
            document.getElementById("demo").href = text; */
            document.getElementById("demo").href.replace(document.getElementById("demo").getAttribute("href"), document.getElementById("demo").getAttribute("href")+val);
            alert( document.getElementById("demo").href.replace(document.getElementById("demo").getAttribute("href"), document.getElementById("demo").getAttribute("href")+val));
        }
    </script>
```

But I am not able to send the language value in the url when i click on href link.
Any help would be appreciated.
Please dont mark this as duplicate, as I haven't found any proper answer for the same.

Comment: Please don't tag JavaScript questions as Java questions, they are not the same.

Comment: Just _set_ the `href` attribute: `element.href = "something else";`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do like this, where you assign the result back to
`document.getElementById("demo").href = '...';`

Also, there is another flaw in your function where the link will not be reset properly, it will increase on every select change, so here is one way to address that, where the original `href` is stored and reused.

```
function myFunction(val) {

  var elem = document.getElementById('demo');

  if (!elem.hasAttribute('data-href')) {
    elem.setAttribute('data-href', elem.href);    
  }

  elem.href = elem.getAttribute('data-href')+val));
}
```

I guess you want to change all links, so here is a simple way using the existing markup

```
function myFunction(val) {
  var elem = document.getElementById('demo');
  var children = elem.parentNode.children;
  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    setHref(children[i],val);
  }
}

function setHref(elem,val) {
  if (!elem.hasAttribute('data-href')) {
    elem.setAttribute('data-href', elem.href);    
  }
  elem.href = elem.getAttribute('data-href')+val));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is the case,

```
 <a id="demo"...>..</a>
```

then you can do it by this way `into JavaScript function`,

```
var pastLink =  document.getElementById("demo").getAttribute("href");
document.getElementById("demo").href = pastLink  + "someNewLink.html";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try something like:


function method(val){
           //capture elements wanna change
            try{
                 var link = document.getElementById("mylink");
                //check value selection
                if(val == 'x'){
                    link.innerHTML = "facebook";,
                    link.setAttribute('href', "http://facebook.com ?lang= somevalue");
                }else if(...){
                  ....
                }
            }catch(err){
               //just to show you differents ways to capture errors
               console.log(err.message) 
               //or 
               document.getElementById("some_div_for_message").innerHTML = err.message;
            }
        return false;
        }
```

Comment: Your code has some serious syntax errors, please update and as well format it properly.

Comment: ty for advice me @LGSon

Answer (score 1):

could you try to do this

```
var href= document.getElementById("demo").href;
 function myFunction(href, val) {
    document.getElementById("demo").href = href + val;
            /* var text = document.getElementById("demo").getAttribute("href")+val;
            document.getElementById("demo").href = text; */
            // document.getElementById("demo").href.replace(document.getElementById("demo").getAttribute("href"), document.getElementById("demo").getAttribute("href")+val);
            // alert( document.getElementById("demo").href.replace(document.getElementById("demo").getAttribute("href"), document.getElementById("demo").getAttribute("href")+val));
        }
```

and you can see thios question in this post 
[How to change the href for a hyperlink using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery)
Expect it help you

Comment: I tried doing this, but for example if I select 'en' for the 1st time and then when I select 'fr' for the 2nd time, then in the url, I am getting like lang=enfr. How to send only the latest selected value is my question?

Comment: the idea is get href value once, becose when you change it first time it will be with last change, so the function  will be (href, value)

Comment: Thej i've edited for no modificacion of first value of hre in link, is that your need?