# jQuery change link href in the body of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a way to change the href of the code below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme1.css">
```

For example from:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme1.css">
```

to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme2.css">
```

This is currently not in the head of the page but in the body. And I only want to target a specific one.

How can I change it using jQuery?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery

Comment: That's for a hyperlink ... mine is not. Mine is for a <link tag. So it's not a duplicate at all

Comment: Link or Hyperlink is still done the same way with jquery.

Comment: I need to target a specific one. Different to that question anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr) or [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop) method like this:

```
$('link[href*="theme1.css"]').attr('href','theme2.css');
```

Comment: Can't I use an ID for target it?

Comment: Yes. You can use if you have.