# how i pass url from javascript to html and download it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

I have developed a website that uses YouTube URL. This website only uses HTML5, CSS and JavaScript. I got the URL of YouTube video as a variable, and now I want to pass it to the HTML page, where it pass to a button. When people click on that button, the video will download. How can I do that? The following is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Search Header</title>

</head>
<body>
<section>

  <input class="downloadmp4" type="submit" value="  Download  MP4   ">

</section>

<script type="text/javascript">

var dow =  'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + foo;

var foo = getParameterByName('id');
    //alert(foo);
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  function getParameterByName(name, url)
    {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
        var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }

  });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The variable is `dow`. That is the complete URL of YouTube video. Now I want to pass it to the "Download MP4 button". How is it possible?

When the ID is passed to that, I also want that when people click on that button, then automatically the video will start downloading.

Two things are there: one is to pass that ID and second when ID is passed then, how it start download?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this. I gave your link an `id="download_link`.

`<a href="#" id="download_link" class="downloadmp4">Download MP4 </a>`

The used `setAttribute` to set the `href` of the link to your `dow`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var dow =  'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + foo;
    var link = document.getElementById("download_link");
    link.setAttribute("href", dow);
    // The rest of your code ...
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I had to comment out the `window.onload` function and the bottom `});` to get it to work. The error was `GetDivElement()` is undefined, which it is in the code you've posted. So try commenting those out and if it still doesn't work, post the error you're seeing.

Comment: could you please write the code for input button, for downloading, as i wrote  function Download(url) {
    document.getElementById('dow').src = url;
};

Answer (score 0):

See this: [How to change the href for a hyperlink using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery),

If you have more than one the download mp4 button, each for a diferent video, you will have to do something to identify the button.

Other way could be the button call a javascript function and on that function you could use the

```
window.location
```

In order to open a new window and do the download.

There is also another way as you may see on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery)

Happy coding :)

Comment: Its not working, neither Id pass nor it start download, can you help, like i use button, to download the video, what will be the code, if i use button, and the id pass to the button, when button clicks, its start downloading, ? is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Where is the action handler for the
   button, i mean how would it react to a "Click Event".

If you have answers to all of the above then the answer to your query would be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Search Header</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<section>

  <input class="downloadmp4" id = "dbtn type="submit" value="  Download  MP4   ">

</section>

<script type="text/javascript">

var dow =  'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + foo;

var foo = getParameterByName('id');
    //alert(foo);
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  function getParameterByName(name, url)
    {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
        var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }

  });

  $( "dbtn").click(function( event ) {
  //Use dow and pass it to your API as you like inside this function....
});
</scr
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i just have the button and that URL, which i want to pass that button, when button clicks, it automatically start download from that URL, ... this is the requirement.

Comment: `$( "dbtn").click(function( event )
 {
 
 //Use dow and pass it to your API as you like inside this function....
  
  
function downloadURI(uri, name) 
  
{
   
var link = document.createElement("dow");
   link.download = dow;
   link.href = uri;
   link.click();
  }
    });`

As i am passing the variable dow in the jquery function, but it s not working.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, make a hidden element...

```
   <p id = "hiddenid" hidden>This paragraph should be hidden.</p>
```

Then, update the element with JS

```
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = urlvar;
```

Then you can access the element in HTML.