# How do you set an Href value using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble changing the href attribute of my HTML code using Jquery

My HTML code is

```
      <div id="main-logo"><a href="http://local.winemag.com"></a></div>
```

I am using the following JQuery code to change my link but for some reason it's not working.

```
      $("#main-logo a[href]").attr('href', 'http://www.test.com/');
```

Comment: Works for me https://jsfiddle.net/x7mnosba/

Comment: How do you run the code that's supposed to change the `href`? Are you sure it's running after the HTML is loaded?

Comment: Make sure your jquery code is either wrapped in a `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` or comes at the end of the `body`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the href for a hyperlink using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery)

Comment: @user2896976 Its at the bottom of my page and wrapped in `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` I'll move it to the very bottom

Comment: @Barmar  Yes I'm sure but I will double check

Comment: @Mariton Are there any errors in the Javascript console? If you add a `console.log()` statement, do you see the message?

Answer (score 6):

to get the current value of the href based on the code provided

`$("#main-logo a").attr("href");`

to set the href new value would be

`$("#main-logo a").attr("href","http://www.test.com/");`

Comment: I will try this and check

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have that line executed once the document is ready:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  //
  $("#main-logo a").attr('href', 'http://www.test.com/');

});
```

Comment: My script is already within `jQuery(document).ready(function($) ...` But I will double check